# How do I find the median of this continous random variable?

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, median, continuous-variables

The question given was to find the median of $X$ given $f(x)=1.1e^{-1.1x}$
Random variable is $X≥0$

I have no issue working out the median of probability density functions with parameters like $1≤X≤5$ , I format them as:

**$\int_1^m$(whatever the equation is)$dx=0.5$**

So would I do the same for one with parameters $X≥0$?

Like, if would $X≥0$ using the original equation of $f(x)=1.1e^{-1.1x}$       turn into $\int_m^0 1.1e^{-1.1x} dx=0.5$

and $X≤0$ would turn into $\int_0^m 1.1e^{-1.1x} dx=0.5$ ?

I would then proceed to solve for m

Comment: Median of a random variable $X$ is any number $m \in \mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb P(X \ge m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb P(X \le m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$. So, precisely, you should find all $m$'s such that $\int_0^m 1.1e^{-1.1x}dx \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and $\int_m^\infty 1.1e^{-1.1x}dx \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^m 1.1e^{-1.1x}dx=0.5$$

integrate and you get:

$$1-e^{-1.1m}=0.5$$

$$e^{-1.1m}=0.5$$

$$m=\frac{\ln(0.5)}{-1.1}=\frac{\ln(2)}{1.1}$$

Comment: Ah okay, so that would be how you format $X≤0$ and $X≥0$ would be formated $\int_m^0 $ ?

Comment: I don't understand your question? @oxy

Comment: I mean that, would the formating of the definite intergral be different depending on whether a ≤ or a ≥ was used? Would a ≤ result in the $m$ value youve written above being on the bottom part of the integral ( ie. $\int_m^0$) and therefore would a ≥ result in $\int_0^m$ ? Because of the whole "greaterthan/lesserthan" thing. Hope that makes sense

Comment: $P(X\ge a)=\int_a^\infty f(x)dx,~~P(X\le a)=\int_0^a f(x) dx$ where $f(x)=1.1e^{-1.1x}$ @oxy

Comment: Ah okay, stay with me for a sec can I run something by you if it works?

Comment: I get pretty much what you are saying, but why does $P(X≤a)$ have a $0$ instead of a $∞$?

Comment: write down the equation that in your mind, I don't understand what you want to say

Comment: Why does $P(X\ge a)=\int_a^\infty f(x)dx,~~P(X\le a)=\int_0^a f(x) dx$ have a $∞$ in the definite integral wheras $P(X≤a)=\int_a^0f(x)dx$ has a $0$ in the definite integral, is it just due to the ≥ and ≤?

Comment: because the random variable $X\ge 0$

Comment: $P(p\le X\le q)=\int_p^q f(x) dx$

Comment: Ah okay finally got it, thanks for explaining that all to me, sorry just starting out in maths so trying to understand some basic things

Comment: you are welcome, note when write $P(X<a)$ it implicitly says $P(X<a)=P(0<X<a)$, because the random variable $X>0$ in this problem. PS: vote my answer :)

Comment: Id love to vote it but dont have enough rep yet sorry~ Will do when I get it though

Comment: ok, no worries!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a remark on this specific exercise (in the general case you already have a detailed answer and so I won't dwell on it any longer).

We can observe that since $f(x) = 1.1 e^{-1.1 x} \mathbb{I}_{\{ x \ge 0 \}}$, we have $X \sim \text{Exp}(1.1)$. For this distribution the median is already known:

$$
m = \frac{\ln(2)}{\lambda} = \frac{\ln(2)}{1.1}
$$

Comment: Thanks man, little observations like that help me a lot, Id upvote you but dont have enough rep

Comment: no worries, thanks fot the thought ;) Glad I was of any help!